# How to setup multiple key value in DFP?

Tags: google-dfp

Hi I have a passback tag and have set two key values my problem is I need the ad to only show when the tag has the two key value. here is the script I am using

```
googletag.pubads().definePassback('networkid/300x600-ss2', [[300,600]]).setTargeting('left-Positions',['ss1']).setTargeting('section',['ads03']).display();
```

I can do this directly on the line item in dfp and create two set of key values but just in case someone forgot to add the other key value I don't want it showing all over the site. which the script is doing right now (it's displaying ad with only one key values).

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must put an AND clause between the two key-value targets. You have probably put OR.

See screenshot.[AND clause in DFP targeting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ow650.png)